# How to pass method result as parameter to base class constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I've trying to achieve something like this:

```
class App {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        System.Console.WriteLine(new Test("abc")); //output: 'abc'
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I can do this passing by an variable:

```
   class Test {
        public static string str; 
        public Test (string input) { str = input; }

        public override string ToString() {
                return str; 
        }
    }
```

works fine.
But, my desire is do something as:

```
class Test {
        public static string input;
        public Test (out input) { }

        public override string ToString() {
                return input;
        }
    }

  System.Console.WriteLine(new Test("abc test")); //abc test
```

Don't works. 
How I do this?
Thanks,advanced.

Comment: Could you just mane Input as a property and doe something like this: `System.Console.WriteLine(new Test("abc").Input);`

Comment: Where is the base class? Why is `str` static in the first example? `input` in the second? What are you *really* trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The variable approach is exactly the correct way, although the variable shouldn't be declared static, and shouldn't be a public field.

```
class Test {
    public string Input {get;set;}
    public Test (string input) { Input = input; }

    public override string ToString() {
            return Input;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have an impression that you're not entirely understand what out keyword means. Essentially when you're writing something like `void MyMethod(out string var)` it means you want to return some value *from* method, not pass it *into* method.
For example there's `bool Int32.TryParse(string s, out int result)`. It parses string s, returns if parse was successful and places parsed number to result. Thus, to correctly use `out` you should have real variable at the calling place. So you can't write `Int32.Parse("10", 0)` because this method can't assign result of 10 to 0. It needs real variable, like that:

```
int result;
bool success = Int32.TryParse("10", out result);
```

So, your desire is somewhat else - it is not in line with language designer's intentions for `out` :)